# Formatting the date based on client OS date format in Angular JS application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, momentjs, angular-moment

I have requirement in our application, where we need show the date format as per the client OS date format.I have used the following code to do this.

---

```
function getFormatedDateTime(date) {
var dateFormated = moment(date).toDate();
return dateFormated.toLocaleDateString();
};
```

---

this working in IE as expected , means when i changed the date format in my PC the date format in the entire application is changing.
But the problem is it not working in other browsers( Chrome, Fire Fox..etc).
we are using moment.js in our application, is there is any option in this to achieve my requirement.
Can any one help me to solve this.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

You can not get users system time format - JavaScript does not reveal information about the underlying OS, for security reasons.

Try this

```
function getFormatedDateTime(date) {
    var dateFormated = new Date();
    return dateFormated.toLocaleDateString();
};
```

This doesn't tell your code what the user's selected date format is, but it lets you return a date in whatever the user's format is.

Link for reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString

Change the system date format will reflect on browser restart.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks! Here is a SB of it in: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-angular-datefilterlocale-qv56xa?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score -1):

You need use to moment with DateTime format like below 
moment(date, 'MM/DD/YYYY')

Comment: This is only works for 'MM/DD/YYYY' but my requirement is , when i changed the Computer date format it should change in the application also.

Comment: You need to setup locale for this, please follow this link https://momentjs.com/docs/ locale section